# How to Autofilll custom attributes field in checkout address for logged customer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, custom-attributes, shipping-address

I created custom attribute fields like DOB, and gender on the checkout page. If you see in the screenshot birthday is a custom address attribute.
[image]

I tried to fill the attribute field(**custdob**) in two ways as mentioned in the screenshot below:
[image]

Can you please tell how I can fill the value in the text field of the custom attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Edit LayoutProcessor File and Modify the field by this approach.

$componentShipping = &$component['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];

```
    $componentShipping['custdob'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'options' => [],
            'id' => 'additional_info'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custdob',
        'label' => __("custdob"),
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'placeholder' =>  __("custdob"),
        'validation' => ['required-entry' => false],
        'visible' => true,
        'sortOrder' => 200,
        'id' => 'custdob',
        'value' => '08/16/2022'
    ];
```

Comment: Hi, Abdul Thank you for your reply.
I added your code in the script and it works fine for the custom email attribute (custom_email) but in case of the radio button and DOB field it is not working.
I am sharing a screenshot of the code that I applied for the custom fields

Comment: Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Abdul Thank you for your reply.
I added your code in the script and it works fine for the custom email attribute (custom_email) but in the case of the radio button and DOB field it is not working.
I am sharing a screenshot of the code that I applied for the custom fields

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custdob'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
                    'options' => [],
                    'id' => 'custdob'
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custdob',
                'label' => 'Geburtstag',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'sortOrder' => 251,
                'id' => 'custdob',
                'value' => '2022-01-03'
            ];

             $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custgender'] =[

                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/checkbox-set',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox-set',
                    'sortOrder' => 0,
                    'label' => 'Anrede',
                    'options' => [
                        [
                            'value' => '1',
                            'label' => 'Frau'
                        ],
                        [
                            'value' => '2',
                            'label' => 'Herr'
                        ],
                        [
                            'value' => '3',
                            'label' => 'Divers'
                        ]
                    ],
                    
                   
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custgender',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => [
                'required-entry' => true,
                 'value' => '2'
            ]
            ];
```

Comment: Are you required to set default values to these controls?

Comment: Yes, these are the required fields.